# Get one record of each group mysql and continuous the same till all record retrieved

Tags: mysql

I have to retrieve each group record first and then continue the same till all record retrieve from my table

```
Id    Name    rank      
-------------------------
1     A       A_data_1
2     A        A_data_2
3     A        A_data_3
4     B        B_data_1
5     B        B_data_2
6     C        C_data_1
7     D        D_data_1
8     C        C_data_2
9     A        A_data_4
```

I have tried

```
select id, name, rank 
from tb 
group by name asc
```

Expected output

```
Id    Name    rank      
-------------------------
1     A         A_data_1
4     B         B_data_1
6     C         C_data_1
7     D         D_data_1
2     A         A_data_2
5     B         B_data_2
8     C         C_data_2
3     A         A_data_3
9     A         A_data_4
```

Comment: What is your PRIMARY KEY? Also, it's very hard to see how the result set relates to the data set.

Comment: id is my primary key

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the data shown in your `rank` column be verbatim what you actually have in your table, but here is one approach using `SUBSTRING_INDEX`:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`rank`, '_', -1) AS SIGNED),
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(`rank`, '_', 1);
```

[image]

### Demo

It isn't clear what the intended meaning of your output `Id` column is.  Clearly, the values there cannot result from the sorting order you expect.  I chose to report what the actual values of `Id` would be after imposing the sort.

Comment: is id  is identity column

Comment: @mangeshukade That's fine, but realize that by sorting your data, the ordering of your `Id` column will also change.  And there is nothing wrong with that (in principle).

Comment: but as mentioned in answer in rank data could be anything

Comment: My answer would still work assuming the `rank` column would always look like: `LETTER_SOMETHING_NUMBER`.  The something in the middle doesn't matter, so long as there are underscores on either side of it.

Comment: no ir could be any data  such as mangesh or sdhf or  dfjkh etc

Comment: Then you didn't ask a very clear or representative question.  Edit your question and please show us the real data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` as follows:

```
SELECT id, name, `rank`
FROM (
    SELECT 
        t.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY id) rn
    FROM mytable t
) x
ORDER BY rn, name
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ibtSq4zGsE1tzW6U61PJyT/0)**:

```
| id  | name | rank     |
| --- | ---- | -------- |
| 1   | A    | A_data_1 |
| 4   | B    | B_data_1 |
| 6   | C    | C_data_1 |
| 7   | D    | D_data_1 |
| 2   | A    | A_data_2 |
| 5   | B    | B_data_2 |
| 8   | C    | C_data_2 |
| 3   | A    | A_data_3 |
| 8   | A    | A_data_4 |
```

---

If you are actually looking to re-number the rows, as shown in your expected output, then you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` again:

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY rn, name) id, 
    name, 
    `rank`
FROM (
    SELECT 
        t.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY id) rn
    FROM mytable t
) x
ORDER BY rn, name
```

Comment: it's not working in MySQL version 5.6.44  and above query is not working